# Share volume between compose containers, with one of them providing its filesystem?

Tags: docker, filesystems, docker-compose, fuse, moby

I'm trying to setup some dockerised NAS, with [mergerfs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs) and samba:

```
services:

  mergerfs:
    build: ./mergerfs  # just debian and install latest release
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    devices:
      - /dev/fuse:/dev/fuse
    volumes:
      - media:/mnt/pool
      - /mnt/data0:/mnt/data0
      ...
   ...

  samba:
    image: dperson/samba
    command: -s'media;/srv/media;yes;no;yes'  # guest allowed, not RO
    volumes:
      - media:/srv/media
    depends_on:
      - mergerfs
    ...

volumes:
  media:
```

The problem is that, while I can read/write to `/srv/media` on `samba`, it doesn't get through to `/mnt/pool` on `mergerfs`.

(I can see this by watching `docker-compose logs mergerfs` while doing `docker-compose exec samba sh -c "echo 'foobar' > /srv/media/test.txt"` which shows nothing in logs, versus the equivalent `exec mergerfs` which *does*.)

How can I make this named volume `media` be a mere 'proxy' for the actual filesystem provided by the `mergerfs` service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in [bind propagation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation).

In particular, here mergerfs needs `media` to be a `type:bind` rather than `type:volume`, so that it can be set to have (recursively) (`r`)`shared` bind propagation - which means that mounts configured by the container will be propagated back to the host.

That is, `media:/mnt/pool` becomes `/mnt/media:/mnt/pool:rshared`.